# Is it possible to get information from contacts associated with a NetSuite Opportunity in Suitescript 2.0 (with the Opportunity as the context)?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I can access sublist items and manipulate those but don't seem to be able to get anything from any associated contacts - they don't even show when you load an Opportunity record in debugger and look at it in the execution log.
What i am trying to do is have a button on an Opportunity that fires a workflow action and calls a suitelet that creates a new custom record (which we can do fine) but i need to add any contacts that are on the Opportunity to the new record.

Answer (score 0):

Contacts are connected to the company record they are associated with.  Contacts appear on your opportunity based on what entity (company) the opportunity is for.  Contacts are not directly related to any opportunity.

See the opportunity entry on the schema browser in help and the contact entry.  You can also see the company entry if that helps.  Link below:

https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_2/schema/record/opportunity.html

If i were trying to solve your issue, I would create the button on the customer and then populate the new opportunity with company related information.  There would be no relation between the opportunities if you did this though.  The opportunities would both show as opportunities related to the same company though.